# VS 2008 created shortcut doesn't show up in "Send To" menu

Tags: visual-studio-2008, setup-project, shortcut, sendto

I have a WinForms application built using Visual Studio 2008.  I added a Setup Project to the solution to create an installation MSI file.  I need the setup project to create a shortcut pointing to the application's executable in the users Send To Menu.  This way when someone right clicks on a file, my application will show in the Send To list and be selected.

I figured out under the file system settings of the Setup project how to add a shortcut to the Users Send To Menu.  The problem is, the shortcut doesn't show in the Send To menu when you right click on a file.  If I manually create a shortcut to my executable the application does show in the Send To menu.

I have read  many suggestions on the web to required registry entries for this to work.  There is a VBS file written by Ramesh Srinivasan which inserts them.  On every system I have tried this on the registry values already existed, so this is *not* the problem.  It seems more to be with the shortcut Visual Studio (or the msi anyway) is creating.

I have experienced this same issue on Windows XP and Windows 7, I haven't tried it on other OS's yet.

Comment: On XP the shortcut should be created in `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\SendTo`. Can you confirm you're doing that. There's no `SendTo` in `AllUsers` so it needs to be created for each user.

Comment: Yes confirmed, that is where the msi installer is placing the file.  Like I said in the write up, the shortcut from the installer doesn't work, but if I replace it with one that I create manually it does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Send To menu requires that the shortcut be a regular shortcut pointing to a executable. The shortcuts created by Visual Studio when building an MSI are advertised shortcuts. Advertised shortcuts do not point to the installed executable, but to the MSI installer, enabling installation-on-demand.

You will have to set the [DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368297(v=vs.85).aspx) property on the MSI in order to have regular shortcuts. Unfortunately, you will have to use a post build event on the installer to set the DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS property - Visual Studio does not supply a simple way to set it.

See the answer by Damien Vogel [to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165781/disableadvtshortcuts-1-disables-all-shortcuts) detailing how to set the post build event.

Comment: Thank you for the information; I hope it is useful for someone.  To get around this and other MSI installer issues I am using NSIS for my installations (http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).