# Deploying .NET 5 WPF application using MSI installer

Tags: .net-core, windows-installer, .net-5, visual-studio-setup-proje

Has anyone used Visual Studio Setup Project to deploy a .NET 5 WPF desktop application? I have been doing this stuff for years, but with .NET 5, things seem to have changed a bit. I tried to follow the steps provided by MS in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2019), which primarily targets .NET Core 3.1, but I couldn't find anything specific for .NET 5.

Unlike .NET Framework WPF applications, where we add **Primary Project Output** to our installer project, this article asks me to add **Published Items** to the installer. I did that but now there is no way to create a "Shortcut" on user's desktop or start menu, because shortcuts require me to select an executable, which I do not have in this case.

A slightly different but related problem is that I can't select my application's icon in the installer project because again I do not have *primary output* of my WPF project in the installer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. After some more experimentation I found the following:

- Creating a shortcut that points to **Published Items** is okay. When user clicks this shortcut after installation, it will simply open the executable in your published folder. So no need of the **Primary Project Output**.
- To use your application icon for the shortcuts and Add/Remove Programs, just add your **ico** file manually to your installation folder and set its **Exclude** property to **true**. This way it will become available in the icon browse dialog, but not injected into user's installation folder.

I also found a couple of more advance solutions that I didn't need in my case, but might be helpful for someone else. There is [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1228013/incorrect-shortcut-in-visual-studio-installer-proj.html) from the vendor themselves that teaches a way of modifying the installer database through script, and [this related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165781/disableadvtshortcuts-1-disables-all-shortcuts) that shows a trick of doing the same using installer UI components.