# Setup Project VS2019 Primary Output is not showing EXE file (DotNet5)

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2019, setup-project, .net-5

I'm not sure if DotNet 5.0 is fully supported in VisualStudio 2019 version 16.9.4, but the Setup Project does not quite work for Winforms DotNet 5.0 .  The Primary Output is showing only a dll, and not an EXE (where it is clearly built and in the */bin/release/net5.0-windows/* folder).

I've created dozens of setup projects in the past, and am 100% positive I'm doing everything as I've done for years. It works fine for DotNet 4.8 projects.

I can't find any answers at Microsoft's site nor any forum I've looked at so far (all the info is for the preview editions of DotNet5 but nothing recent).
Anyone else have this problem?  If so, any workarounds for this bug/feature?

Comment: To clarify: Only the *.dll, *.ico, and *.runtimeconfig.json  files are in the Program Files folder after setup is executed

Comment: It is not lying to you, the primary output of a .NETCore/.NET5 project is a DLL.  The EXE is merely the CLR host, plays the same role as dotnet.exe.  Same kind of deployment model as Java, Python, etc, the user supplies the runtime and you only supply the parts that implements your program.  Still using the ancient Setup project feature for .NET5 is courageous, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65583713/deploying-net-5-wpf-application-using-msi-installer) might help.

Comment: Okay, I see.  I figured as much.  The setup project hasn't changed in a decade, so what was I thinking that I could code without having to roll my own installer or buy a 3rd party installer? lol!  (personally, I think it's a bad idea by MS to force developers to continually reinvent the wheel - Installers should be a standard thing by now.)